# Unable to find a javac compiler while packaging titanium module

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

Titanium studio unable to find Javac compiler when i am trying to package a module from studio. But able to package from build.xml in terminal. What could be the problem.

```
Executing build.xml...
C:\Users\tarak\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.3.v20130318143059\module\android\build.xml:166: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Appcelerator\Titanium Studio\jre"
```

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME in our environmental variables? Do you have the [correct version of JAVA](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio-section-30086257_SettingupTitaniumStudio-SystemRequirements)?

Comment: Hi Josiah, I have double checked JAVA_HOME ,it is pointing to jdk. When i do ant build of build.xml ,it works fine. But when try to build from studio then only JAVA_HOME points to "C:\Program Files\Appcelerator\Titanium Studio\jre".

Answer (score 1):

Make java home variable point to a **jdk** installation, not **jre**.